# module 'tensorflow.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I had to import tensorflow as following because tensorflow 2 doesn't support the 'placeholder' function:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Further the code snippt uses '**contrib**' function in the below co

```
def encoding_layer(rnn_size, sequence_length, num_layers, rnn_inputs, keep_prob):
    '''Create the encoding layer'''
    
    for layer in range(num_layers):
        with tf.variable_scope('encoder_{}'.format(layer)):
            cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(rnn_size,
                                              initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1, seed=2))
            cell_fw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell_fw, 
                                                    input_keep_prob = keep_prob)

            cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(rnn_size,
                                              initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1, seed=2))
            cell_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell_bw, 
                                                    input_keep_prob = keep_prob)

            enc_output, enc_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, 
                                                                    cell_bw, 
                                                                    rnn_inputs,
                                                                    sequence_length,
                                                                    dtype=tf.float32)
    # Join outputs since we are using a bidirectional RNN
    enc_output = tf.concat(enc_output,2)
    
    return enc_output, enc_state
```

The final code block is:

```
# Build the graph
train_graph = tf.Graph()
# Set the graph to default to ensure that it is ready for training
with train_graph.as_default():
    
    # Load the model inputs    
    input_data, targets, lr, keep_prob, summary_length, max_summary_length, text_length = model_inputs()

    # Create the training and inference logits
    training_logits, inference_logits = seq2seq_model(tf.reverse(input_data, [-1]),
                                                      targets, 
                                                      keep_prob,   
                                                      text_length,
                                                      summary_length,
                                                      max_summary_length,
                                                      len(vocab_to_int)+1,
                                                      rnn_size, 
                                                      num_layers, 
                                                      vocab_to_int,
                                                      batch_size)
    
    # Create tensors for the training logits and inference logits
    training_logits = tf.identity(training_logits.rnn_output, 'logits')
    inference_logits = tf.identity(inference_logits.sample_id, name='predictions')
    
    # Create the weights for sequence_loss
    masks = tf.sequence_mask(summary_length, max_summary_length, dtype=tf.float32, name='masks')

    with tf.name_scope("optimization"):
        # Loss function
        cost = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(
            training_logits,
            targets,
            masks)

        # Optimizer
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

        # Gradient Clipping
        gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
        capped_gradients = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -5., 5.), var) for grad, var in gradients if grad is not None]
        train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gradients)
print("Graph is built.")
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

I came across some answers which suggested me to install tensorflow 1.14, however, that also gives the following error:

```
❯ pip install tensorflow==1.14
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.14 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.14
```

Please help.

TIA.

[UPDATE]

I tried installing tensorflow 1.14 through conda, and got the following error:

```
❯ conda install tensorflow==1.14
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining @/win-64::__cuda==11.1=0:  67%|████████████████████████████████                | 2/3 [00:00<00:00, 13.28it/s]/                                                                                                                       -failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - tensorflow==1.14 -> python[version='3.6.*|3.7.*']
  - tensorflow==1.14 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.1=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.1=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.1
```

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi This is clearly not a problem with pip. However, I did what you said and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: That's strange. My pip version is `21.0.1` and `pip install tensorflow==1.14` works fine without any problems

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi my pip is 21.1

Comment: You are using Python 3.8, but `tensorflow==1.14` only supports Python up to 3.7. Install 3.7 if you need to use `tensorflow==1.14`, or [migrate the legacy code to 2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).

Answer (score 4):

if you want to Use tf.contrib libraries use Tensorflow ==1.14.0 or 1.15.0
it also requires Python ==3.6/3.7.

Answer (score 1):

try this :`import tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 as tf`